# Setting output parameters in SELECT statement with an IF EXISTS check

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make an efficient SQL stored procedure for retrieving user data from my database, but I am running into a syntax issue I can't seem to figure out.

Basically, I want to assign my output variable within my SELECT statement. I also want to see if the user actually exists by IF EXISTS. Unfortunately, I can't seem to do both.

Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].FindUser(@UserID binary(16), @UserExists bit OUTPUT, @Name 

nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS (SELECT @Name = Name FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID)
    BEGIN
        SET @UserExists = 1
    END
RETURN
```

Currently, it gives me an "SQL46010 :: Incorrect syntax near @Name." error.
If I remove IF EXISTS, the statement compiles fine!

Why does the IF EXISTS check cause a syntax error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set @UserExists = 0;

select @Name = Name, 
       @UserExists = 1
from Users
where UserID = @UserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID)
BEGIN
    SET @UserExists = 1
    /* do other stuff here select user name or whatever */
END
```

If there is a record for `@UserID` in `users table` Selecting `1` will return true for exists clause and control will enter the `BEGIN..END` block.

Comment: I wanted to try to set my Name variable somewhere without doing another query.

Comment: @Eaton Exists will only yield `True` or `False` you cannot retrieve data from it.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz you should only down vote an answer when you are 101% sure that it is wrong, we are not playing guessing game here

Comment: dude sorry that was my mistake

Comment: Be friendly, guys. (:

Comment: Would like 6 select statements in this block be a performance concern? I have a few other things besides Name I would like to get out.

Comment: @Eaton if you are only assigning values to multiple variable and not retrieving any data you can do it in one select statement.